# Reduce nested "if's" in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have three functions that run asynchronously where the return function is part of the function call. What I need to happen is "If function A and function B return a good value (not an error) then do function C." What I have right now is "If function A returns a good value, then call function B, if function B returns a good value, then call function C."

Is there a better way to do this in javascript?

The code I am working with is as follows:

```
// Login to amazon
// function 0       
amazon.Login.authorize(options, function(authResponse) {
    if ( authResponse.error ) {
        // user not logged in. Do nothing.
        alert('oauth error ' + response.error);
        return;
    }
    else
    { // good response
      // Call function A
      amazon.Login.retrieveProfile(authResponse.access_token, function(response) {
          if ( response.success ) { // good response
              // Prepare to call function B   
              // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
              AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: 'abc' });
              AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
              AWS.config.credentials.params.Logins = { 'www.amazon.com': authResponse.access_token };

              // Call function B. This could be called at the same time as function A                               
              AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
              if (!err) {
                   // Both Function A and Function B came back with good results. 
                   // Now can call function C and do more work
              } else {
                   // error in function B
              }
          } else {
              // error in function A
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: For starters, if your `if` returns, there is no need to have the `else`, as it's guaranteed to be elsewise.

Comment: Here's a decent tutorial on using something called `promises` https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: As long as you're working with just callbacks this is the way to go. You may consider using named functions, but essentially that doesn't help you with what is often called "callback hell". A common alternative is using Promises, which provide a different way of chaining the calls, but you are still stuck with three functions. The "best" solution would be to have async/await, but that will only be in ES7. At this time, it is simulated by state machines by some languages that compile to JavaScript, though.

Comment: @BrianGlaz would you have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30669642/1092711)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are building Pyramid of Doom. You can avoid that by chaining promises (I've used a polyfill from https://www.promisejs.org/). You can chain as many functions as you want, as long as they are returning promises. Additionally, you can avoid `else` block byte throwing an exception early.

```
var accessToken;

(new Promise(amazon.Login.authorize.bind(amazon.Login, options)))
    .then(function (authResponse) {
        if (authResponse.error) throw res.error;

        accessToken = authResponse.access_token;

        return new Promise(amazon.Login.retrieveProfile.bind(amazon.Login, accessToken));
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        if (!response.success) throw 'Profile retrieval failed';

        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: 'abc' });
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
        AWS.config.credentials.params.Logins = { 'www.amazon.com': accessToken };

        return new Promise(AWS.config.credentials.get.bind(AWS.config.credentials));
    })
    .then(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // call function C here
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // do something with error
    });
```

You may want to check the documentation on the API you using. Maybe there are versions of those methods that return promises already.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/tovokarole/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce complexity by not putting those functions inline, but rather defining them outside.
In this example
amazon.Login.authorize(options, authorizeCallback(response));

```
function authorizeCallback(response) {
    if ( authResponse.error ) {
        alert('oauth error ' + response.error);
        return;
    }
    amazon.Login.retrieveProfile(authResponse.access_token, retrieveProfileCallback);
}

function retrieveProfileCallback(response) {
    if ( response.success ) { // good response
      // Prepare to call function B   
      // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
      AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: 'abc' });
      AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
      AWS.config.credentials.params.Logins = { 'www.amazon.com': authResponse.access_token };

      // Call function B. This could be called at the same time as function A                               
      AWS.config.credentials.get(getCredentialCallback);

  } else {
      // error in function A
  }
}

function getCredentialCallback(err) {
    if (!err) {
        // Both Function A and Function B came back with good results. 
        // Now can call function C and do more work
    } else {
        // error in function B
    }
}
```

And so on, javascript treats functions as first class citizens, so you can treat them as values, and pass them around.

Comment: Hi Gustavo,  With this solution I still would call function A and then have the call the function B within function A correct? Is there a way to do it with what you propose to call function A, call function B, wait for response from A and B and if both good continue?

Comment: Yep, I understand that you're trying to remove if/else, but still need to do error checking. One of the problems of working with a lot of callbacks. I would suggest going with that approach (the code wouldn't be cluttered, and each if/else would be in a separate function) See the updated code snippet

Answer (score 0):

as Gustavo demonstrated, you could define the inline functions
in the outside and then reference it.
I would recommend this for your example.

But that does not reduce your nested conditionals.
Sure, the authorize function looks shorter, but it has always the nested conditionals inside it.

If you have more and more nested conditionals, than your search keyword should be 'Asynchronous Control Flow Patterns'. Then you'll find libraries, who solve this asynchronous coding hell.

Take a look at the async library.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: The third solution would be a Pubsub/Observer Pattern. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh201955.aspx , but for this example it could be too much. The best approach is Gustavos solution.